# Create Azure like cloud from LAN?

Tags: azure, batch-processing, lan

I work with environmental numerical models and have recently started using Microsoft Azure for large batch runs. Azure is great, but the costs add up rather quickly.

I work at an organizations that has hundreds of computers on our LAN that just sit around most of the time.

Would it be practical to use these LAN computers to create a computing cloud? The computers do not need to be that fast, I just want hundreds of processors for parallel batch applications.

Answer (score 0):

Do not think that it is possible to run Azure Batch against local machines.

But you can reduce the cost of running an Azure Batch by 80% by using low priority VM's. The way that it works is that you get a VM. but if someone comes along willing to pay normal price they get it.

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-low-pri-vms

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/batch/